# How to pipe output from C# application using cmd to text?

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm running an app that uses a console app in the background

When I do this in cmd `read-info.exe Myfile.file >fileinfo.txt` it will create the file fileinfo.txt in the route folder.

But when I do it in code nothing happens, why?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog theDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    theDialog.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = theDialog.SelectedPath.ToString();

        string command = "read-info.exe " + textBox1.Text +"> File.txt";
        string retur = CMD(command);
    }
}

static string CMD(string args)
{
    string cmdbat = "cd " + Application.StartupPath.Replace("\\", "/") + "\r\n";
    cmdbat += args + " >> out.txt\r\n";
    cmdbat += "exit\r\n";
    File.WriteAllText("cmd.bat", cmdbat);

    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new     System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = "";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\cmd.bat";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    string cmdOut = File.ReadAllText("out.txt");
    File.Delete("cmd.bat");
    File.Delete("out.txt");
    return cmdOut;
}
```

Comment: Tilak is right , But it looks like you maybe need to rethink what you are doing , it look pretty complicated for what the end result is

Comment: Can you [edit] the title of your question so that it contains real words? *Hot to outupt* has no meaning, and will be valueless to future readers in a search result. (Yes, I could do it for you, but then you'd miss two lessons: 1) Your question should be clearly stated and have meaning, and 2) How to edit your posts.)

Comment: its just supose to give me a file i will then read from the file and then extract only a certain part of the files information and display it but no matter what it doesn't work

Comment: @KenWhite Do you ever find that that works? I tried for a while, but it never stuck so I just edited stuff myself. Sorry for ruining your lesson, but I hope the message comes across anyway.

Comment: thanks for editing sorry just really frustrated not getting this to work

Comment: @J.Steen: Surprisingly, fairly well. Once in a while someone takes it as a personal insult, which is never intended (and I try to be careful with wording).

Comment: @KenWhite I'll have to rethink my strategy then and try again. It was a year since my last run of 'try to be nice and educate the new people'. =)

Comment: Do you need a SPACE character before the '>' in the string `"> File.txt"`, to prevent the '>' being interpretted as part of the first argument to the `readinfo.exe`?

Comment: @MikeofSST id doesnt matter because doing it through cmd doesnt matter or does it ? the reason im doing it this way is to execute an console application in the background of the win forms app

Comment: It looks like the batch file will end up with `read-info.exe Myfile.file >File.txt >> out.txt`?

Comment: @crashmstr if i comment File.Delete("out.txt"); it just reads in out.txt Usage: read-info.exe myfile.file

Answer (score 2):

See this - I tnink it is what necessary: http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput

Copied from the link above:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
//
// Setup the process with the ProcessStartInfo class.
//
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"C:\7za.exe"; // Specify exe name.
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
//
// Start the process.
//
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    //
    // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
    //
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.Write(result);
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Posting a link to an external site is really unwelcomed here. Links die and then your answer becomes totally useless.

Comment: Ok, I copied what is important.

Answer (score 0):

use [cmd /C](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) for running console commands.

```
string command = "cmd /C read-info.exe " + textBox1.Text +"> File.txt";
```

Comment: if i put that into my code it just locks up and have to shut it down from within visual studios

Comment: I am trying to understand your code, it looks complicated. Scratching my head in getting which command actually gets executed. You need to prefix cmd /c to the actual command to make it work.

Comment: could u explain more ? basically it creates the cmd.bat and executes from there and then deletes the cmd.bat afterwords

Answer (score 0):

Got It Working Thanks to @crashmstr

it outputs file as out.txt so just had to comment out File.Delete("out.txt");